# Spark Dataframe Group By Operation and Picking N values from each group

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark data-frame of the following structure:

```
Operation|RequestURL|RequestBody|IsGetRequest|IsPostRequest
```

and a variable : `val n = 100`

I want to perform `Group-by` on the `Operation` column in the data frame. Then, I want to Fetch `RequestURL` and `RequestBody` columns for `n` requests (no ordering) in each of these groups (create a new `data-frame/rdd/map` of this). If a group has less than n requests, I want to duplicate some of the rows in that group to ensure that the number of requests I fetch from each group is the same.

Need help in figuring out how this can be done in an optimized way. I am open to using any language (`python/scala`) and also convert the data frame to pandas or a hash-map of key and values, if this is not possible to be done using `spark data-frame`.

I have seen some solution on stack-overflow using grouping and order-by and then using windows partition function to get `topN` values. 
How my question is different - For my case, there is no `ordering`. Also, I want to ensure `fetching equal number of requests` from each group.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it using Windows Partition function. Followed it up with converting the resulting dataset to map of [String,List(Strings)] using groupBy() and toMap functions, traversing the map and replicating the rows using list operations.